# React-Native: Cannot set state from form values

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a simple login form in React-Native using the tcomb-form-native component. I've created the method handleChange for setting the values to the initial state and the handleForm for submiting. Right now with my code when I'm typing something into the input fields the content is deleted and is replaced with the placeholder (no console output) and when I press the submit button im getting the error "undefined is not an object (evaluating this.refs.form)". Is there a better way how to do it?

Here is how I imported and set up everything:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

var t = require('tcomb-form-native');

var Form = t.form.Form;

var User = t.struct({
  username: t.String,
  password: t.String
});

var options = {
  auto: 'placeholders',
  fields: {
    password: {
        password: true
    }
  }
};
```

Here are my class and methods:

```
class Login extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        },
        isLoading: false,
        error: false
    };
    this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({value});
}
handleSubmit() {
    var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
    //update the indicator spinner
    this.setState({
        isLoading: true
    });
    console.log(value);
}
```

And this is how im rendering everything:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={styles.logo}>
                <Image source={require('../icon.png')} />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Login</Text>
            <Form
                ref={(f) => this.form = f}
                type={User}
                options={options}
                onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({value})}
                value={this.state.value}
            />
            <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this.handleSubmit}
                underlayColor="white">
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't Use Bind When Passing Props](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props)

then you can do like this

```
onPress={this.handleSubmit}

handleSubmit = () => {...}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but unfortunately I cannot test it yet because I couldn't manage to fix the handleChange, at the moment everything im adding in the input fields are automatically deleted and display the placeholder ... I've tried to use the same principle from above but doesn't look that it did.

Comment: Ive modified the code above with my last changes. Looks like it doesnt delete them anymore but my emulator stopped working now so I don't have yet a console to test it.

Comment: I managed, the problem with the text is that I was binding to an empty variable and your answer help me understanding the onPress methods. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In `TouchableHightlight`, you need to define: `onPress={this.handleSubmit}` as:

`onPress={() => this.handleSubmit()}` or

`onPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}`

In addition, `ref` should not be string nowadays in React (+ Native) (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute), but e.g.:

`ref={(f) => this.form = f}`

and then you refer to it with `this.form`.